# How to declare an array in awk

Tags: awk

I have used awk to write a script. I am wondering how to **declare an array** in awk.

I have read the [gnu awk manual](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_12.html#SEC113) and found nothing about **declare**.

i want to test if index `ind` is in awk array `arr`.

```
echo 'awk' | awk 'BEGIN {arr} {if ('1' in arr) arr[ind] = 1}'
```

i do not declare `arr` as an array previously and run this in awk gives me such an error.

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: attempt to use scalar `arr' as an array
```

Comment: No need to declare array in awk. Just populate values into it like arr[1] = 5 and access them like arr[index]. For more details, see this http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial `arr` in the `BEGIN` block "declares" it to be a scalar. That's what is confusing awk. Just remove that.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the delete statement to declare an empty array:

```
BEGIN { delete arr[0] }
END { 
    print "len", length(arr)
    if ("1" in arr) {
        print "astonishing"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do this with a gawk multidimensional array? I'd like to say that `arr["people"]` is an array, but I haven't managed without first `arr["people"]["dummy"]++;delete arr["people"]["dummy"]`

Comment: Due to awk's manual, no:

" NOTE: You may need to tell gawk that an array element is really a subarray in order to use it where  gawk  expects  an  array  (such  as in the second argument to split()).  You can do this by creating an element in the subarray and then deleting it with the delete statement."

Comment: Hah! That's a bit sad, but ok. Thanks for the reference.